# Failed to find configured root that contains ***(Path) - FileProvider Issue

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am in trouble with this issue, couldn't find any way out yet.

I have configured a Fileprovider in manifest.

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.name.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

where the `@xml/file_paths` is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.package.name/files/Pictures" />
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images_" />
</paths>
```

And my java code is like below

```
private void selectImageFromCamera() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.e("selectImageFromCamera", "Error: " + ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            try {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.package.name.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("selectImageFromCamera", "Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The method createImageFile()

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    Log.e("storageDir", "storageDir: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    myCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

But I am always getting problem when creating photoUri, to be exactly at below line.

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.package.name.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
```

Error in try catch

```
.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.name/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170417_115925_834197983.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is com.package.name? set it to your package name

Comment: `com.package.name` is a dummy just like my package name in Manifest file

Comment: com.package.name is your app package name??

Comment: here, yes its my app package name.

Comment: did you check in file manager that image is exist?

Comment: and change Pictures to Pictures/

Comment: yes, the files are exist

Comment: i am using like:  <paths >
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0/" path="."/>
</paths>

Comment: tried, but not worked :(

Comment: but for that you need to change in manifest and camera capture code.

Comment: check my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42948718/6756514

Comment: `<external-files-path
        name="my_images_" />` Change to ` <external-files-path
        name="myimages" path="." />`. And remove the first one.

Comment: let me try that solution